# How to set nonProxyHosts for a SOCKS proxy?

Tags: java, proxy, localhost, socks

I want to set the `nonProxyHosts` list for a SOCKS5 proxy, i.e. the list of hostnames to which a direct connection should be used.

As the [oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html) describe, there are options named `http.nonProxyHosts` and `ftp.nonProxyHosts` to set proxy exclusions for HTTP and FTP, but there is no specific setting for SOCKS proxies.

I tried `http.nonProxyHosts`, but this doesn't affect SOCKS connections.

The SOCKS proxy is set up via:

```
System.setProperty("socksProxyHost", "192.168.10.10");
System.setProperty("socksProxyPort", "3128");
```

But this causes that even DB connections to `localhost` are using the SOCKS proxy, which is unacceptable. 
 
How is this supposed to be used? How can I exclude certain hosts from the proxified connections?

Comment: I need the same functionality.  I'm afraid that nonProxyHosts for SOCKS is not currently implemented.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use the `socksNonProxyHosts` system property; this is undocumented, but exists in Oracle JDKs 8 thru 11, and probably others too.

```sh
java -DsocksProxyHost=mySocksServer -DsocksProxyPort=8888 -DsocksNonProxyHosts=127.0.0.1 [...]
```

---

TL;DR

The property `socksNonProxyHosts` is found in the source code for [sun.net.spi.DefaultProxySelector](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/net/spi/DefaultProxySelector.java) (thanks to @rince)

However, the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html) for the Java networking properties implies this doesn't exist, so its use may be unstable:

> Once a SOCKS proxy is specified in this manner, **all** TCP connections will be attempted through the proxy.

(Emphasis added)

You might be able to use the `Proxy` and/or `ProxySelector` classes, but:

- `ProxySelector` is only applicable if your application uses `URLConnection` to establish connections.
- `Proxy` is applicable for arbitrary sockets ... but only if you can supply the `Proxy` object as a parameter to the relevant `Socket` constructor calls.  (And you would need logic to supply different `Proxy` objects depending on what your code is trying to connect to.)

There's a [bug for this RFE for this](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/net/spi/DefaultProxySelector.java). The ticket suggests another workaround.  Apparently, if the `java.net.useSystemProxies` property is `true`, then (on some platforms) the default proxy selector will respect exclude hosts specified in the appropriate system proxy settings.

Comment: To anyone else reading this, it looks like that bug is fixed for Java 8(b86).

Comment: @xdhmoore can you point me to some documentation on this bug fix?

Comment: @Tucker It's the one linked to above.

Comment: The bug doesn't name the actual property, you have to go looking in the source for DefaultProxySelector.
The property is socksNonProxyHosts

Comment: Indeed, as of the Java 9 release, they still haven't documented this property in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html

Comment: `ProxySelector` is used for `Socket` instances for me (Java 1.7)