# SocketImpl and JUnit/Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, junit4

I'm trying to make Socks v4 work out of the box in java.net, and I seem to have succeeded! 
Roughtly the code that I'm using is this:

```
    class SocketImplFactorySocks4 implements SocketImplFactory {
        @Override
        public SocketImpl createSocketImpl() {
            System.out.println("Socket implementation triggered");
            try {
                return socketSocks4Factory();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new Error("Can't go further");
            }
        }

        private SocketImpl socketSocks4Factory() throws
                [...] {
            Class<?> aClass = Class.forName("java.net.SocksSocketImpl");
            Constructor<?> cons = aClass.getDeclaredConstructor();
            if (!cons.isAccessible())
                cons.setAccessible(true);
            Object socket = cons.newInstance();
            Method method = socket.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setV4");
            if (!method.isAccessible())
                method.setAccessible(true);
            method.invoke(socket);
            Field field = socket.getClass().getDeclaredField("useV4");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            Object value = field.get(socket);
            return (SocketImpl) socket;
        }

    }
```

Long story short, it works when I create a socket and pass -DsocksProxyHost and -DsocksProxyPort.

My problem is when I use the same code in my junit test, I can check with Reflections that Socket.impl.useV4 is set to true, socksProxy* settings are set systemwide, but when I use my socket, it avoids using proxy altogether (I can see it in wireshark).

It's either JUnit or Gradle, but I've reached my limits. Please advice on where should I go next. build.gradle.kts for reference:

```
tasks{
    test{
        systemProperty("socksProxyHost", "localhost")
        systemProperty("socksProxyPort", "8080")
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it took me way too much time to figure it out, but I did. My initial goal was to test my Socks v4 server code, but there were two problems on my way:

1) Even though Java Socket has support for Socks v4 as client, it is not enabled by default. And there is no way to flip the toggle.

2) Having solved #1, I tried to write E2E test to smoke the whole thing, but for some reason it was **avoiding going into the Socks proxy**, even though the toggle (useV4) was true. This is what I came with here on SO.

To solve the first problem, I implemented SocketImplFactory (see above in the question).
What helped to tackle the topic question was my admin background, even though it didn't kick in until recently. :) I separated the original suspects (JUnit and Gradle) and made the test in a standalone psvm file. The test didn't work, it still avoided going through the proxy. And this is when it hit me: exception for localhost!

Basically, there is a hardcoded exception for localhost(127.0.0.1, ::, etc) deep in Java core library. After some searching I came across *DsocksNonProxyHosts* option. Which didn't help, as you might have guessed already :)
Eventually I ended up at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445875/how-to-set-nonproxyhosts-for-a-socks-proxy) answer, which mentioned that I might need to implement ProxySelector. Which I did:

```
    static class myProxySelector extends ProxySelector {

    @Override
    public List<Proxy> select(URI uri) {
        List<Proxy> proxyl = new ArrayList<Proxy>(1);
        InetSocketAddress saddr = InetSocketAddress.createUnresolved("localhost", 1080);
        Proxy proxy = SocksProxy.create(saddr, 4);
        proxyl.add(proxy);
        System.out.println("Selecting Proxy for " + uri.toASCIIString());
        return proxyl;
    }

    @Override
    public void connectFailed(URI uri, SocketAddress sa, IOException ioe) {
        if (uri == null || sa == null || ioe == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Arguments can't be null.");
        }
    }
}
```

The whole socket setup looks like this:

```
        private void setupSocket() throws IOException {
        Socket.setSocketImplFactory(new SocketImplFactorySocks4());
        ProxySelector proxySelector = new myProxySelector();
        ProxySelector.setDefault(proxySelector);
        proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 1080));
    }
```

Now everything I wanted works: I'm both able to E2E-test my socks4 code and can do it localhost.